# Issue with jQuery .get() in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, get

I am fetching some content from another page using jQuery .get() like this -

```
$.get("http://www.somesite.co.uk/generalsite/PopDownMenu", function (htmlContent) {
    $("#masternav").html(htmlContent);        
});
```

This script works fine in all browser except IE.

Is it my script or the page I am fetching from?

Comment: If it works in other browsers, I can't see any reason that wouldn't work in IE. Does the callback fire at all?

Comment: Is this a third party site that your scraping? In that case, you may be a victim of Same Origin Policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @JamesAllardice, I can't find a reason why it would work on other browsers as he seems to be violating the same origin policy.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - The fact that he says it works in other browsers may mean that he isn't violating the same origin policy (i.e. this code runs from watchfinder.co.uk).

Comment: @JamesAllardice, he is trying to send an AJAX request from `http://thewatch.watchfinder.co.uk` to `http://www.watchfinder.co.uk` which is a violation of the same origin policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am fetching some content from another page using jQuery .get() like this

You seem to be violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You cannot send cross domain AJAX requests. So unless your site is hosted on `http://www.watchfinder.co.uk/` you cannot send AJAX requests to this domain for security reasons. You may take a look at the [following article](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) for possible workarounds.

Comment: My site is hosted on http://thewatch.watchfinder.co.uk, is this anything I can do on the page to allow access from thewatch?

Comment: @seanjacob, no, you are violating the same origin policy restriction. `thewatch.watchfinder.co.uk` and `www.watchfinder.co.uk` are considered cross domain. Read the article I have linked in my answer for possible workarounds.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: surprisingly, the uri from the OPs question seems to work just fine with cross-domain ajax calls. Might be that there is some kind of CORS running ? Works fine in FF and Chrome at least. Check http://jsfiddle.net/MfVea/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Ok thanks I will post a solution if I find one.

Comment: While CORS is supported by the majority of browsers, not all versions have it, though. See the full list in this link: http://caniuse.com/cors. Long story short, best not to rely on its availability if your user base is the general audience.